# Create and Update a table from database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a database with the following fields:

- eventname (the name of the event - text)
- datestart (the start date of the event - e.g. ../../..)
- dateend (the end date of the event - e.g. ../../..)

I need to create a table with 3 columns, and however many rows depending on how many events there are.

Here is the code I'm using at them moment to store the database data in an array:

```
 $allevents = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY datestart ASC");
    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($allevents)){
```

As I said, I then need to to display the data in a table.

I'd really appreciate some help as to how to achieve this, as I'm very new to PHP.

Comment: Do *not* use `mysql_` functions as they're deprecated, use `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Comment: The code you included does not store data, it retrieves it.

Comment: Its not quite clear what you want to accomplish here... You want to transfert data from one table to another that you create dynamicly??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Are you familiar with Alex Garret's FREE ten-minute tutorials on TheNewBoston or (his own site) phpAcademy.org?

These may help you greatly:

[200 PHP videos at TheNewBoston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11)

[PHP tutorials at phpAcademy.org](https://phpacademy.org/courses/php)

Basically:

```
$allevents = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY datestart ASC");

$out = '<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Address</td></tr>';

while($event = mysql_fetch_array($allevents)){
    $name = $event['name'];
    $addr = $event['addr'];

    $out .= '<tr>';
    $out .= '<td>' .$name. '</td>';
    $out .= '<td>' .$addr. '</td>';
    $out .= '</tr>';
}

$out .= '</table>';

echo $out;
```

Comment: Despite the downvotes, I am in no way associated with Garret or his sites - but I've used them extensively myself and recommend them frequently. FRE-QUENT-LY. And, btw, I learned about them from a post just like this, on SO.

Comment: Just a quick question, how would I change the appearance of the table e.g. borders, alignment etc?

Comment: CSS is most useful. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) and [css-tricks here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css3-zebra-striping-a-table/)

Comment: The down vote is'nt for the provided tutorials. It is because you only provide them and did'nt answer the question (at first). Since you provide an clear answer and a exemple of code I am 'undownvoting' you and 'upvoting' this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a foreach loop to cycle through your array and echo your html content.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

First : Create the function for convert dates, here this code :

```
function convDate($str_date, $format = "d-m-Y") 
{
    // Ubah string ke date 
    $date = new DateTime($str_date);

    // Kembalikan niilai dengan date_format
    return $date->format($format);
}
```

Finaly.. you can retrieve the query with dates formatted

```
while($event = mysql_fetch_array($allevents)){
    echo $event['eventname'] . '-' . convDate($event['datestart'], 'd/m/Y') . '-' . 
         convDate($event['dateend'], 'd/m/Y');
}
```